# Rails: add relationship with other table for Devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to add an input to my Devise user sign_up form in order to add a team name. I created a specific table for Teams and I created a relationship: Users belong to Team. Team has many users.
The problem is I need to add a Team_id when submiting the sign_up form. How can I save the value of the Team input in the register form to the Team table and get the Id in order to save it to the team_id entry in Devise User table?

My Sign Up form:

```
<div class="container_index">
  <h2>Sign up</h2>

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :team %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :team %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

My user schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_users_on_team_id"
  end
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :team) }
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :current_password, :team) }
      end
```

Thank you.

Comment: add team_id to permitted parameters, both for create (sign_up) and update (account_update)

Comment: How can I save through the Devise controller the Team name to the Team table?

Comment: do you also want to create a team record while creating or updating a user?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a team record and then take it's Id and create the user with the team_id

Comment: try something like that - https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/f4914b9fb39e1ee440806e31c7733bdb

maybe  this can be refactored by activerecord callbacks, but try and see if it works.